# implementation of bayes and svm classifiers in opencv3

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to implement `Bayes` and `SVM` classifiers in `OpenCV 3.3`. I've written following code for `SVM`:

```
int main()
{
// Load data

FileStorage fs("newStorageFile.yml", FileStorage::READ);

// Read data

Mat test_data, test_labels, enrol_data, enrol_labels;
Mat train_labels = Mat::zeros(650, 1, CV_32S);
Mat train_data = Mat::zeros(650, 600, CV_32S);

fs["train_data"] >> train_data;
fs["train_labels"] >> train_labels;
fs["test_data"] >> test_data;
fs["test_labels"] >> test_labels;
fs["enrol_data"] >> enrol_data;
fs["enrol_labels"] >> enrol_labels;


Ptr<ml::SVM> SVM_Model = ml::SVM::create();
SVM_Model->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
SVM_Model->setKernel(ml::SVM::RBF);

Ptr<ml::TrainData> trainingData = ml::TrainData::create(train_data, ml::SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels);
SVM_Model->trainAuto(trainingData);

return 0;
}
```

But I've got following exception error on `SVM_Model->trainAuto(trainingData)`.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x755B5608 in SVMimplemantation.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00D8DF58.
```

And also about `Bayes` classifier, I've written following code:

```
int main()
{
// Load data

FileStorage fs("newStorageFile.yml", FileStorage::READ);

// Read data

Mat test_data, test_labels, enrol_data, enrol_labels;
Mat train_labels = Mat::zeros(650, 1, CV_32F);
Mat train_data = Mat::zeros(650, 600, CV_32F);

fs["train_data"] >> train_data;
fs["train_labels"] >> train_labels;
fs["test_data"] >> test_data;
fs["test_labels"] >> test_labels;
fs["enrol_data"] >> enrol_data;
fs["enrol_labels"] >> enrol_labels;

Ptr<ml::NormalBayesClassifier> bayes = ml::NormalBayesClassifier::create();
Ptr<ml::TrainData> trainData = ml::TrainData::create(train_data, ml::SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels);
bayes->train(trainData);

Mat output, outputProb;

bayes->predictProb(test_data, output, outputProb);

return 0;
}
```

About this case, I've got following Exception on `bayes->train(trainData)` too.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x755B5608 in BayesImplementation.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00A5D79C.
```

To be able to compile the project, Ive uploaded my dataset [here](http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/hrHrCRpdCW/newStorageFile.yml). What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked all your pointers? All the create functions that return Ptr<> will return false on failure. Check after each create with something like if (!trainData) throw("Bad pointer"); Edit: That is, they won't return false, but the Ptr<> class has a bool conversion so you can check if it's valid.

Comment: @Zebrafish thanks, I've checked it. but the problem is somewhere else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the type of `train_label`. Try with following:

```
Mat train_labels32S = Mat::zeros(train_labels.rows, 1, CV_32S);

for (int i = 0; i < train_labels.rows; i++)
    train_labels32S.at<int>(i, 0) = train_labels.at<int>(i, 0);
//some code
    Ptr<ml::TrainData> trainingData = ml::TrainData::create(train_data, ml::SampleTypes::ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels32S);
```